# put <strong> or <em> tags inside <h1>, <h2>, ... tags affect to seo?

Tags: html, validation, tags, seo

```
<h1> <strong> Heading Text </strong> </h1>
```

1. Putting em, strong or b tags inside header tags is bad coding?
2. Is that affect to SEO?

Comment: This may helpful http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42249/strong-and-em-tags-inside-h1-and-h2-and-seo-on-database-driven-website

Answer (score -2):

Only google has silver bullet.

Just use simple rules

- one H1 per page
- one H2 per page
- a little H3
- use **strong** **em** if you haven't another choice. Assume that for blind
  people this tag increase sound level in text-to-speach.

For SEO will be better if you create smart system crosslinking inside you site. This boost ranks better than this games with tags.